# Makefile pattern rule with multiple targets

Tags: makefile

Below is my makefile:

```
src/config-comp/%.o: ../src/config-comp/%.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking: GCC C Compiler'
    gcc-4.8 -std=gnu11 -DDEBUG=$(DEBUGOPT) -I"$(ROOT_DIR)/../.local/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall $(GPROF) -c -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -MT"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -o "$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
```

In src/config-comp, I have two C source files, one is config-comp.c and the other one is config-proxy.c. I read GNU make book saying that

> "If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the rule’s
>   recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe is
>   executed only once to make all the targets."

However, my output is as following:

```
Building file: ../src/config-comp/config-comp.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc-4.8 -std=gnu11 -DDEBUG=0 -I"/home/cheng/crane/libevent_paxos/target/../.local/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall  -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/config-comp/config-comp.d" -MT"src/config-comp/config-comp.d" -o "src/config-comp/config-comp.o" "../src/config-comp/config-comp.c"
Finished building: ../src/config-comp/config-comp.c

Building file: ../src/config-comp/config-proxy.c
Invoking: GCC C Compiler
gcc-4.8 -std=gnu11 -DDEBUG=0 -I"/home/cheng/crane/libevent_paxos/target/../.local/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall  -c -MMD -MP -MF"src/config-comp/config-proxy.d" -MT"src/config-comp/config-proxy.d" -o "src/config-comp/config-proxy.o" "../src/config-comp/config-proxy.c"
Finished building: ../src/config-comp/config-proxy.c
```

This means the recipe has been executed two times, right? But according to the quote above, it should be executed only once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple targets means something like:

```
%.foo %.bar: %.c
```

And your rule will be responsible for making both `*.foo` and `*.bar`. The single execution applies to targets that have the same stem: if `baz.foo` and `baz.bar` both have to be made, the rule will only be executed once, but if `baz.foo` and `blargh.bar` have to be made it will be executed two times (for the stems `baz` and `blargh`).

In your case you have a single target (`src/config-comp/%.o`), so it'll be executed for every object file you build (which is what you want most of the time).